# How to read multiple images in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I would like to read and display 4 images in Python 3.7, but I only know how to read them one by one.Is there any better code I can use to read them at a time. My code is as follows, it looks like redundant. Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_1 = Image.open('...file pathway',"r")   
plt.imshow(image_1)
plt.show()   

image_2 = Image.open('...file pathway',"r")   
plt.imshow(image_2)
plt.show()   

image_3 = Image.open('...file pathway',"r")   
plt.imshow(image_3)
plt.show()   

image_4 = Image.open('...file pathway',"r")   
plt.imshow(image_4)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It depends what you are really trying to do. If you are trying to display all the images in a directory, use globbing. If the filenames are easily derived from a common stem and a number, use a `for` loop. If the filenames are all totally different, like `cat.png`, `dog.jpg`, make a list of filenames and iterate over it.

Comment: Thank you, I would make a list of filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop to repeat an action.
First of all, use a dictionary or list to store the file pathways. If you only need to display them once, a list is fine.

If these images need to be reused later in the code, or something else the following doesn't accomplish, edit the question with details of what you need to do and I'll edit my answer accordingly.

On to the code. I'll refer to the list of file pathways as file_list.
`for x in file_list:` will loop through the list, assigning each value in it to x, executing the code in the code block following the for loop, and repeating.
Remember to indent the code block properly.

```
for x in file_list:
    image = Image.open(x,"r")
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
```

All done!

Comment: Thank you, the file_list did work. That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can read multiple images in a file

```py
import glob
import cv2

images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("path/to/files/*.png")]
```

OR you can use this

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

def process(filename: str=None) -> None:
    """
    View multiple images stored in files, stacking vertically

    Arguments:
        filename: str - path to filename containing image
    """
    image = mpimg.imread(filename)
    # <something gets done here>
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(image)

for file in images:
    process(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding some functionality to other answers, as they said you can use a `for` loop to load the images but they don't solve how to show them at the same time hence you can add `subplot` to show all images together at the same time as follow:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

src = 'Imagenes/' # Images source

files = os.listdir(src) # Getting the files to copy

for idx, image_src in enumerate(files):

  image = Image.open(f'{src}{image_src}',"r")  

  plt.subplot(2, 3, idx+1), plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray') #2, 3 because you wanna show six images

plt.show()
```

The result would be like:

[image]

Hope this can support the rest of the answers :)

Comment: Thank you. Good to know this useful help.

Comment: I was wondering how to hide these grid for these images? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

And, using Canvas from tkinter:

```
# For many examples using tkinter.Canvas, see:
# Programming Python by Mark Lutz

from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

def loadImages():
  path = './media/'
  imgCount = 3
  
  imgPaths = [f'{path}{i}.png' for i in range(imgCount)]
  
  images = [Image.open(path) for path in imgPaths]
  
  # Note: trying to use ImageTk.PhotoImage(),
  # before creating the Tk root, will fail.
  imagesTk = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(image) for image in images]
  
  return imagesTk

def displayImages(canvas, images):
  xOffset, yOffset = 0, 0
  for img in images:
    canvas.create_image(
      xOffset, yOffset, image=img, anchor=tk.NW
    )
    xOffset += img.width()
    yOffset += img.height()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  
  root = tk.Tk()
  
  images = loadImages()
  
  canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1024, height=768)
  canvas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, 1024, 768))

  button = tk.Button(
    root, 
    text='Load&Show', 
    command=lambda: displayImages(canvas, images)
  )
  
  button.pack()
  canvas.pack()
  
  root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you. Good to know this new knowledge.